# How to organize columns for different device sizes in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am writing my first Bootstrap 3 based website and I have the following in mind. As you can see, for large and medium devices I need 3 columns, and for extra small devices I want 1 column. But for small devices I want 2 columns and the third column to be at the bottom occupying the whole row. The code below does not work, for the medium device only the blue div is displayed. How can I get my design working? Or Is there another better approach?

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:red; height:120px;">

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background-color:green; height:120px;">

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="background-color:blue; height:120px;">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all for `bootstrap CSS` to work you need to add the `bootstrap stylesheet` preferably in the `<head>` section of your document.

Second, change the order of the bootstrap class statements starting from `xs` and up to `lg`.

**This works:**

**Note:** run the snippet at the bottom, click on the full screen link and resize the browser window to see the effect.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:red; height:120px;">

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:green; height:120px;">

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4" style="background-color:blue; height:120px;">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Boostrap class statements are already added in my project ( I am using version 3). I tried what you suggest but the result is the same.

Comment: @user3059248 I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, change the order in `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"` to `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4"`.

Comment: @user3059248 I changed bootstrap 4 for bootstrap 3, to prove it works. I have a feeling the problem is that your bootstrap.css file is not at the top of your css files in the head section. If it is not, put it to be the first css file in the head.

Comment: @user3059248 try also running the snippet and clicking on the `full page` link on the right, then resizing your browser, you will see it works, so if it doesn't work for you and the moving of the bootstrap.css above others in the head also doesn't solve your problem then you have other issues (you will need to post more of your HTML or CSS).

Comment: I just noticed that you are referencing Bootstrap v3.3.7 and I have v3.0.0. I changed and it worked correctly. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: @user3059248 your welcome, I'm glad to hear that :) peace